# How to list up sites you have permission to

Tags: web-part, search, permissions, site-collection, security

We have a SharePoint 2013 on-prem environment. We are using both sites and site collections as project rooms. On the front page of our intranet I need to list up all sites and site collections which a user is following, and I need to list up all site and site collections where a user is a member.

I don't know about any out of the box functionality to achieve this, and I want to avoid writing server side code with endless iterations.  I am looking for some tips to do this in an optimal way.

Comment: You could use the search engine, excuting a KQL query. This is a great way since the search will return trimmed results

Comment: Thanks for the tips. In KQL, is it possible present a result with sites where the current user has write-permissions ? (Because I don't want to list up sites where a user has read only access)

Comment: Nope, KQL is only checking read permissions.

Comment: Looks like custom programming is the only way to do it then. Thanks a lot for your input.